# How to display data of input field on another page

Tags: php, wordpress, html, wordpress-theming

i have input field for emails and i need the data that was entered by the user to be shown on another page

```html
<input style="width:456px; height:30px;" class="adv_onus_fields" name="adv_onus_email" autocomplete="off" type="email" placeholder="'.__("Email","Advinim").'"/>
```

Comment: it is a wordpress project and im editing in the theme editor because the developer didnt use any of wordpress features and he added everything in the pages, the client need the emails to be shown on administrator page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply have to wrap the input into a form and specifiy a target like this.

```
<form action="/destination.php" method="get">
<input style="width:456px; height:30px;" class="adv_onus_fields" name="adv_onus_email" autocomplete="off" type="email" placeholder="'.__("Email","Advinim").'"/>>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">   
</form>
```

On the page you want to use the variable write `$_GET['adv_onus_email']` to access it.

Another way of doing it is starting a session with `session_start()` and saving the variable in the `$_SESSION` array.